# Ajax not posting when value based on selectbox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What I have here is ajax that's post information into textbox from database. This ajax work's in input field, but when I tried to use select box it doesn't working. Why is that?

not working

```
<select id="tag"><option value="">none</option><option value="crs">crs</option></select>
```

working

```
<input name="tag" id="tag" type="text" value="" />
```

**Index.php**

```
<select id="tag"><option value="">none</option><option value="crs">crs</option></select>
<input name="output" id="output" type="text" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('input[id="tag"]').change(function() 
{
var prjt_code = $("#tag").val();

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "autocomplete-ajax.php",
data :"prjt_code="+prjt_code,
dataType:'html',
type:'POST',
   success:function(data){
  //alert(data);
    $('#output').val(data);
   }
  });
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

**autocomplete-ajax.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['prjt_code'])) {
$prjt_code = $_POST['prjt_code'];

$sql = $mysqli1->query("SELECT * FROM project WHERE project='$prjt_code'");

while($row1 = $sql->fetch_assoc())
  {
  $code = $row1['project_code'];
  }
echo $code;
}
?>
```

Comment: `input[id="tag"]` do you notice the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are targeting input[id="tag"] when you want select[id="tag"]

http://jsfiddle.net/releaf/U28jb/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('select[id="tag"]').on('change', function() {
 var prjt_code = $("#tag").val();
    alert(prjt_code);
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "autocomplete-ajax.php",
    data :"prjt_code="+prjt_code,
    dataType:'html',
    type:'POST',
    success:function(data){
      //alert(data);
      $('#output').val(data);
    }
  });
  return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: ID selector! `#` !!!!!!!! - Also - unless the `.change` has some native functionality you want to cancel, why `return false`?

Comment: I totally agree. I just copied the example code provided by @user3631428. Since it's not a click or a submit function there's no default behavior to prevent so we don't even need e.preventDefault() here.